# Error undefined object (whereas it was defined)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently making a top down shooter HTML5 game using canvas (JavaScript), here is my problem:

When I shoot, a function check if there is a collision with an enemy or not, if yes, it destroy the enemy and the bullet, BUT sometimes (randomly) the game chashes and returns an error:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
at collides (game.js:274)
at checkBulletHits (game.js:177)
at Game (game.js:346)
```

In this error "undefined" is the last bullet I shoot, but this time the bullet is `undefined` for a reason I don't understand.

Here is the code involved:

```
var bullets = [];
var enemies = [];

function checkBulletHits() {
    if (bullets.length > 0 && enemies.length > 0) {
        for (j = bullets.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (k = enemies.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                if (collides(enemies[k], bullets[j])) {
                    enemies.splice(k, 1);
                    bullets.splice(j, 1);
                    player.points += 10;    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function collides(a, b) {
    return  a.x < b.x + b.w &&
        a.x + a.w > b.x &&
        a.y < b.y + b.h &&
        a.y + a.h > b.y;
}

checkBulletHits();
```

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/H2Cw1g5j

Comment: Your `collides` function is attempting to work with `a.x` and `b.x`, but `x` is not in scope there. You must locate where you've declared `x` and make sure it has the proper value by the time `collides()` attempts to use it. As for your main issue, `collides()` is supposed to be receiving two arguments, but the error indicates that it is being called with, either just one, or the second one has a value of `undefined` when it is used.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: scope doesn't have anything to do with the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a collision, you remove the bullet at index `j`. Then the loop continues to the next enemy, and there's another check for the bullet at index `j`.

That bullet no longer exists, so you're calling `collides(enemy, undefined)`.
Then, in `collides`, this will obviously throw an error: `undefined.x`.

Break out of the loop when you have a hit. Add a `return` statement at the end of the `if` block.

Comment: Excellent, @JackNeth! Did this answer your question, or is there still something unclear?

Comment: This is actually only true if the match is found for the last element of the `bullets` array, where `j === bullets.length -1`.  Otherwise splicing the array and using an index to refer to the element will not be `undefined`  (it will just check the previous bullet again).

Comment: it answerd my question, i can finaly continue working without the game crashing every time :D